# Can PTFE be dissolved by aqua regia?

Tags: acid-base, cleaning

At the moment I am cleaning crucibels in aqua regia. I was wondering, whether I could stir it with a standard PTFE stirring bar or not?
I am not sure if it is needed or if the normal flactuation in the liquid is enought but usally stirring makes things better.

There is no doublebond in it to be attacked by Cl-radicals and C-F is one of the strongest bonds so I could not think of any reaction that could occur. But maybe there is some crazy side reaction I am not aware of.

Comment: There is no problem. Stir away!

Comment: See for instance https://www.calpaclab.com/teflon-ptfe-compatibility/

Comment: @Buck this is Nitric/sulfuric not nitric/hydrochloric acid

Comment: I know but see one of the answers which provides a general reply to your question. PTFE is resistant to a broad range of acids.

Comment: You can skip stirring unless doing a kind of cleaning race.

Comment: While I generally agree that there is **an** answer in the linked question that also answers this question, it can easily be missed when only looking at the question an top answer. (I know; who wouldn't read the whole thing?!) So maybe it would be beneficial to quote the relevant portions here and link to the original for context. (Or write a completely new answer.)